# How to add new directory (with files and folders) to a VOB in CCRC 7.0.1?

Tags: rad, clearcase-remote-client, vob

I am using CCRC 7.0.1/RAD 8.5. There is a new project (directory) to be uploaded under a VOB.  This VOB does not have any other directory. This directory(to be added) has many folders and files.
There is a main branch as well as an Integration branch and Development branch. Usually I promote from Development to Integration to main if i am making changes to code.

So under which branch should I add this new directory. Is it under main or should I add to Development branch and promote/merge it to Integration and main? Can someone please help me – I have never done this before. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by the dev branch, before promoting it (deliver) to the integration branch.

You can add your folder by following "[Creating new files and directories from the CCRC interface](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21245019)"

[image: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21245019&aid=1]